# How to read from a folder without knowing the names of the file's contents (java)

Tags: java

I'm wondering how I would go about loading all images from a folder without knowing the names of each image.

Comment: Any coding effort so far?

Comment: @Mauren Any research at all :P

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to accomplish and let us know what you have done to try and help yourself. What doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [`File#listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)

```
File path = new File("path/to/the/folder/with/the/images/in/it");
File[] files = path.listFiles();
```

You can also use a [`FileListFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) to determine what should be returned from calling `listFiles`, allowing you to pre-filter the list

Comment: your answer is better than me. +1

Comment: @Ashish I suspect we might find that the OP is trying to read images from an embedded source and not the file system, but they've provided no context from which to work...

Comment: ok, thanks. I have just added filter for the extension as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have only jpg file or subdirectory in parent folder. You can use something like this.

```
public void loadImageFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            loadImageFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            loadImage(fileEntry.getAbsoluteFile());

        }
    }
}

private void loadImage(File file)
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG file", "jpg", "jpeg");
if(filter.accept(file){
try 
{
   BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
    }
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}


 }

final File folder = new File("/home/you/Desktop");
loadImageFilesForFolder(folder);
```